# Вывод html, css и javascript кода на странице средствами javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Пытаюсь разобраться с js, не как не могу понять как вывести код html, css и js как текст.
Пример:

```
document.write('<b>hello</b>') //на странице должно вывестись <b>hello</b>
```

Comment: а выводится ...?

Comment: Выводится просто hello без тегов

Comment: Во-первых, document.write('<b>hello<\/b>') - экранируйте слэши. Во-вторых, браузер не показывает исходный код, а показывает интерпретированный.

Comment: Ну а как его заставить выводить исходный код? Экранировать?

Comment: `document.body.textContent = '<b>hello</b>';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
document.write('<xmp><b>hello</b></xmp>');
```

Но тег `xmp` считается устаревшим. Можно использовать `code`

```
document.write('<code>&ltb&gthello&lt/b&gt</code>');
```

Comment: Работает, спасибо большое

Comment: @ConstantineVolochshuk, пожалуйста.